# Creating Private Dns zone group automatically creates a record

Tags: a-records, azure-private-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

I am creating a private endpoint, dons zone group, and adding a record for the resource in dns zone using azure cli but it is giving an error in adding a record task, I think while creating dns zone group it is automatically adding a record in dons zone, can someone confirm if this is true or something else is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe upon creation of the private endpoint, with the integration of private dns record, the private dns zone and record would be created for it as referenced here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns-integration